# API with between array

Tags: api

We recevently update to 4.7.2 and this seems to have broken something in the API regarding the BETWEEN operator.

This used to work:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'receive_date' => array('BETWEEN' => array("2015-10-01", "2015-12-31")),
));
```

Now it returns no results. However less than and likewise operators return correct results.

Is it a bug or am I using it wrong?

Comment: did you test this in the API explorer of the demo version of CiviCRM? http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/dashboard